# Why is my class an incomplete type inside itself?

Tags: c++

```
class test {
public:
    test(int i) : t(10) {
        cout << "cst" << i << endl;
    }

    static test ins;
    const test t;// 1
};
```

On line 1, the compiler fails with an error:

> incomplete type is not allowed

Why is that?

Comment: `test` would be infinite size if the compiler allowed that. Since every `test` object has a `test` object that has a `test` object ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler parses code from top to bottom.  When the compiler encounters the declaration of `t`, it hasn't yet seen the end of the declaration of `test`, hence why `test` is an "incomplete type" at that location.  The compiler doesn't know yet if there are any more data members following `t`, so it doesn't know how much space to reserve for `t` within each instance of `test`.

Basically, a `class` (or `struct`) cannot include a *non-static* instance of itself.  Doing so would lead to a recursive declaration that never ends until the compiler fails.

However, a `class`/`struct` can include a *pointer or reference* to itself, since a pointer/reference has a fixed size at compile-time.  For example, this is how linked-lists are implemented.